# Is there a way to evaluate a variable within a string literal in a bat script?

Tags: batch-file

Let's say I have a variable containing a string like so...

`set test=%%userprofile%%\Desktop\test.txt`

If you were to echo %test% you'll see...

`%userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt`

How would a person take that value and let's say delete that file?  If I do the following...

`del %test%`

I get...

`"The system cannot find the path specified."`

Somehow I need it to evaluate the literal "%userprofile%" into the user's real user profile location to find the file on their desktop.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `call del %test%`

Comment: @PcLoadLetter Note with the above that a single caret `^` in a variable will be consumed via escaping through the use of call. This can be prevented using substring modification: `call echo(%test:^=^^%`. It may be rather unlikely users will have usernames containing carets, however it is a possibility you should be aware of.